# R retrieving values from inside a data frame in a list

Tags: r

I have a list with several data frames in it:

```
weekday <- c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat")
data1 <- c(letters[1:7])
data2 <- c(letters[8:14])

df1 <- data.frame(day = weekday, val = data1)
df2 <- data.frame(day = weekday, val = data2)

my_list <- list(list_1 = df1, list_2 = df2)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to pull the data that matches a specific day in a specific data frame. I know how to extract the data frame `list_1`,

```
> my_list[["list_1"]]
  day val
1 Sun   a
2 Mon   b
3 Tue   c
4 Wed   d
5 Thu   e
6 Fri   f
7 Sat   g
```

And how to extract a specific row when I know the index of the day:

```
> my_list[["list_1"]][1,]
  day val
1 Sun   a
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to get a specific row when I want to match a value. An example of what I think should work is:

```
my_list[["list_1"]][list_1$day == "Sun",]
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(my_list[["list_1"]], list_1$day == "Sun", ) : 
  object 'list_1' not found
```

I know I could just subset the df to a temporary variable and then it would be easy, I'm just trying to make this compact and follow good practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `my_list$list_1$day == "Sun"`. Your `my_list` is essentially a nested list (since a data frame is also a list), so you can chain the `$` operator to get all the way down to the columns. So your code could be

```
my_list$list_1[my_list$list_1$day == "Sun", ]
```

As you can see, that code is not an easy read. For this reason, I like `with()`. This is handy here since a list can be coerced to an environment, and it is a lot easier to read.

```
with(my_list, list_1[list_1$day == "Sun", ])
```

Comment: If I want to then extract `val` from that row, how can I do it inside of `with( )`? I can't just add `[["val"]]`, it comes back as `NULL`

Comment: @JonathanH - Is `with(my_list, list_1$val)` (or `with(my_list, list_1[["val"]])`) what you want?  That returns the entire `val` column as a vector.

Comment: P.S. - You can inspect `with()` using stuff like `with(my_list, ls.str())` and `with(my_list, ls())`

Comment: I'm trying to return a single value in `val` that matches a specific value of `day`. I'm ok with using the ugly version of the code in your answer because I can just tack `[["val"]]` on the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subset` or `filter` from `dplyr` if you want to save some typing:

```
subset(my_list[["list_1"]], day == "Sun")
#   day val
# 1 Sun   a
```

Comment: I am trying to use `[`, `[[`, and `$` and avoid a call to `filter` or `subset`